# How to solve the ORA-01758 problem without delete data and add primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I want Write ALTER TABLE SQL statement to add a column to the table. The column is classified as NUMBER datatype, NOT NULL attribute, and primary key.
But it shows ORA-01758.

```
ALTER TABLE INSURANCE
ADD (INS_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

If I select DEFAULT 0, it really solves the problem, but I cannot set up a primary key and INS_ID shows 0, not (null)
Because this table's data is from a excel document, what should I solve it without delete data?

If I must delete data how restore it easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you can either:

- provide a default value so oracle can fill the column as it creates, satisfying the constraint or
- create the column as nullable, fill it with relevant data, then enable the not null restriction/make it the primary key after it has data or
- empty the table

1 is not an option for you, because the values will have to be unique if they are to be a primary key. You could consider associating the column with a sequence or making it an identity column though

2 is a likely option for you if an auto generated incrementing number is no good as a PK (for example the key data is already known or calculated)

3 is something you've already said is not an option

---

Give some thought to the ongoing maintenance requirements - every front end app that writes data into this table will need to be upgraded to understand it has a primary key unless you're using a sequence/identity or similar that provides a unique value  for the row. If there will be a lot to update and you dont care to have a PK in a particular form or from some existing value/relationship elsewhere, having an auto number PK can be helpful. If this data needs to relate to existing data that has a key, you need to upgrade front end apps so they can respect the new PK

Comment: Thank you, but this project want to me add a column into the table. The INS_ID is classified as NUMBER datatype and NOT NULL attribute. An altered table is shown below like this
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyK1i.png

the problem is because of attribute is NOT NULL. but this alterable shows INS_ID is (null), how can i make NOT NULL attribute and shows (null) in INS_ID. I do not want to delete data.

Comment: Sometimes you have to get there in steps. Step #1 - add the column. Step #2 - populate it. Step #3 - alter it so it's NOT NULL.